# Reorder grid toolbar buttons

Tags: acumatica

How can we reorder the buttons in a grid toolbar?

I have defined a button to add rows to grid with a custom logic in my extension and added as a custom tool bar button to the PXGrid. I set the default AddNew button enabled = false.

```
 public PXAction<RQBiddingVendor> InsertSplitLine;
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Insert Line", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
 [PXButton(FieldOrdinal=0)]
 public virtual void insertSplitLine()
 {//SOME LOGIC HERE TO INSERT RECORD TO CACHE}
```

Now the custom button is showing as third.
REFRESH, DELETE, INSERT
[image]

I would like to move the insert before delete. tried using the field ordinal but doesnt work. how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this.

I set the following

> **Grid** > ActionBar > GroupIndex = 1, Order = 1
>
> **Grid** >> **ActionBar-CustomItems** > ActionBar > GroupIndex = 1, Order = 0